# PostgreSQL: full text search not working as intended

Tags: postgresql

I recently started using PostgreSQL and i'm currenly studying the full text search function. I tried following this guide, the problem is that the output in pgadmin is different from what i see in the page:

https://www.compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/

Using this command returns the following list of lexemes

```
SELECT to_tsvector('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');

'brown':3 'dog':9 'fox':4 'jumped':5 'lazy':8 'over':6 'quick':2 'the':1,7
```

While in the tutorial the same command returns another list of lexemes

```
'brown':3 'dog':9 'fox':4 'jump':5 'lazi':8 'quick':2
```

Another problem is that when i search for the word 'foxes' pgadmin returns False, while in the tutorial it returns true.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') @@ to_tsquery('foxes');
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: because it depends on you full text search configuration whether or not you have included stop words. seems like your full text search default settings is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one seems more likely that you have installed postgresql in another locale and based on [Postgresql documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TEXT-SEARCH-CONFIG) :

- default_text_search_config (string)

Selects the text search configuration that is used by those variants
of the text search functions that do not have an explicit argument
specifying the configuration. See Chapter 12 for further information.
The built-in default is pg_catalog.simple, but **initdb will initialize
the configuration file with a setting that corresponds to the chosen
lc_ctype locale, if a configuration matching that locale can be
identified.**

so I think if you run  your query with 'english' configuration , you will  get the same result as the tutorial:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english','The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
```

also you can run this command to see which catalog your configuration is using :

```
SHOW default_text_search_config;
```

if you want to chnage your default full test serach configuration to 'english' you can use this command:

```
SET default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the reason why the results were different. The language setting in pgadmin was already set to 'english' but the full text search was set to another language.